# Mean points end up next to boxplot bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put a mean in a boxplot with facets but the mean points does not end up on top of the boxplot but next to them. Any suggestions as how to fix this so that the mean points end up on top of the boxplots?

[image]

Here's the code for the ggplot2

```
(
  df %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = inlet_gas, y = Furfural_uptake, fill = soil_type) +
  stat_summary(fun="mean", color="darkred", geom="point",  
               shape=15, show.legend=FALSE)+
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_hue() +
  labs(x = "", 
       y = "Uptake (% of blank)", 
       title = "Linalool uptake") + 
  labs(fill="") + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(measurement_type), scales = "free", ncol = 1L)
)
```

And here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(measurement_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("No VOC addition", "13C mix addition", 
"VOC addition [low]", "VOC addition [medium]", "VOC addition [high]"
), class = "factor"), soil_type = c("forest", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "heath", "heath", "heath", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "heath", "heath", "heath", "heath", "heath", 
"forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "heath", "heath", "heath", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", "forest", 
"forest", "forest", "heath", "heath", "heath", "heath", "heath", 
"forest", "forest", "forest", "forest"), Furfural_uptake = c(1.2, 
1.02, 1.22, 1.27, 1.21, 1.17, 1.22, 1.09, 1.03, 1.09, 0.95, 0.92, 
0.98, 1.04, 0.64, 0.62, 0.58, 0.62, 0.59, 0.6, 0.61, 0.55, 0.63, 
0.55, 0.73, 0.66, 0.73, 0.69, 0.7, 0.71, 0.82, 0.77, 0.7, 0.52, 
0.62, 0.57, 0.56, 0.47, 0.44, 0.6, 0.5, 0.52, 0.72, 0.68, 0.64, 
0.65, 0.67, 0.63, 0.59, 0.64, 0.69, 0.7, 0.57, 0.58, 0.54, 0.58
), inlet_gas = c("N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", 
"N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", 
"N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "O2", "O2", 
"O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", 
"O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", "O2", 
"O2", "O2", "O2", "O2")), row.names = c(NA, -56L), groups = structure(list(
    inlet_gas = c("N2", "N2", "O2", "O2"), measurement_type = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("No VOC addition", "13C mix addition", 
    "VOC addition [low]", "VOC addition [medium]", "VOC addition [high]"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:14, 15:28, 
        29:42, 43:56), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position=position_dodge(0.9)` like the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = inlet_gas, y = Furfural_uptake, fill = soil_type) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun="mean", color="darkred", geom="point",  
               shape=15, show.legend=FALSE, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9))+
  scale_fill_hue() +
  labs(x = "", 
       y = "Uptake (% of blank)", 
       title = "Linalool uptake") + 
  labs(fill="") + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(measurement_type), scales = "free", ncol = 1L)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bappa Das! Do you know how I can show the mean (darkred square) in the legend?

Comment: Make `show.legend=FALSE` to `show.legend=T`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Bappa Das, however how would I do if I wanted to have the mean symbol in the legend above the two others. Now I get the mean on top of the other symbols in the legend (see picture in the original question)